# SmartGit equivalent to TortoiseHg 'Browse at Revision'

Tags: git, tortoisehg, smartgit

I regularly use TortoiseHg's 'Browse at Revision' if I just want to see the state of a particular file at some old commit (even if the file itself wasn't changed in that particularly commit).

We also have Git repositories and we're using SmartGit. I know I can turn on the 'Show Unchanged Files' filter but this does not give me a correctly nested view of directories/files. Does anyone know how/if this is possible in SmartGit?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible: as of version 18.1, SmartGit does not support a nested Directory - Files view in the Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of turning on "show unchanged files", juste type the name of the file you want to see (or part of it) in the selector at the top. You get a restricted list of files which ignore the filters, so you can easily right-click the one you want, "compare with working tree".